# Error 500 Sending JSON POST Request to API

Tags: c#, json, rest, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app in Xamarin.Forms (Shared Project Library) that sends a list of custom types (just a document number and a file type enumeration) to a locally hosted API.

If I capture the JSON string and send it from Postman, everything works fine, but as soon as I run the httpClient.PostAsync from the app, I receive the following error:

> {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Cache-Control:
>   no-cache Pragma: no-cache Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version:
>   4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 25 May 2017 16:00:44 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1
>   Content-Length: 36 }}

I'm at a loss a to what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone help, please?

Type:

```
class EmailFiles
{
    public string docNumber { get; set; }
    public EmailFileTypes.EmailFileType type { get; set; }
}
```

Request:

```
        List<EmailFiles> files = new List<EmailFiles>();

        if (chkShipping.IsToggled)
        {
            EmailFiles file = new EmailFiles();
            file.type = EmailFileTypes.EmailFileType.CustomerFile;
            file.docNumber = Helpers.GlobalVariables.gSOLookup.PackList;
            files.Add(file);
        }
        if (chkClosed.IsToggled)
        {
            EmailFiles file = new EmailFiles();
            file.type = EmailFileTypes.EmailFileType.ClosedFile;
            file.docNumber = Helpers.GlobalVariables.gSOLookup.Invoice;
            files.Add(file);
        }
        if (chkInvoice.IsToggled)
        {
            EmailFiles file = new EmailFiles();
            file.type = EmailFileTypes.EmailFileType.Invoice;
            file.docNumber = Helpers.GlobalVariables.gSOLookup.Invoice;
            files.Add(file);
        }

        string url = SetUrls.urlMtApi + "/api/EmailFile/?emailAddresses=" + strEmails;

        string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files);
        //Results in: "[{\"docNumber\":\"234273\",\"type\":1},{\"docNumber\":\"633007\",\"type\":2}]" - which works in Postman!!

        StringContent content = new StringContent(strJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Web Service:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public string EmailFile([FromBody]string jsonfiles, [FromUri] string emailAddresses)
    {
        List<EmailFiles> files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailFiles>>(jsonfiles);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You need to debug that 500 error server side. That means the server is throwing an exception somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually deserialize the json body, just let the model binder do it for you by using correct parameters:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public MyModelReturnType EmailFile([FromBody] List<EmailFiles> files, [FromUri] string emailAddresses)
{
     // the framework has already deserialized the json request for you
}
```

If you use `string` instead of the true model for your parameter the server will not be able to bind your request body to it, because it will expect a JSON **string** (surrounded by double quotes `"`), and this could cause a model binding exception that will lead to a 500 error in your client.

The same is for the return type, just use whatever class you want your client to receive as return type and do not use `string` if you want to send it Json.

Comment: Awesome!!  Thank you so much.  I never would have figured that out on my own.  Everything is working perfectly now.  Thank you again.